# Database.SqlQuery -> Entity Framework Objects

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to use Database.SqlQuery in Entity framework to run a custom JOIN operation.  I don't want to use LINQ to do the JOIN because it is doing a horrible job of generating performant SQL on the backend and I just want to control what it does.

So my question is -- How can I get a set of objects (it's a JOIN from table A to table B, and I want both an object of type A and an object of type B) back out from an INNER JOIN operation on Database.SqlQuery?

Comment: That is one of the most interesting features of Dapper: https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#multi-mapping

Comment: So concretely how would I use that here -- do you have an example you can share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As far as I know](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/233?PendingVoteId=233) the `SqlQuery` method uses property names to map columns to properties.

So you can just declare the class with properties of query and then split it to pair `A` and `B`.

Example:

```
public class AB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

var abs = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<AB>(@"SELECT A.Id, A.Name, B.Title
                                            FROM A JOIN B ON A.Id = B.Id");

var a_and_bs = from ab in abs
               select new
               {
                   A = new A { ab.Id, ab.Name },
                   B = new B { ab.Title }
               };
```